# How to direct users to opt for a particular social sign-in?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, user-research, login, social

Suppose I am having login form as :

[image: social sign in]

How can I direct users to opt in for **Google sign-in** preferably against Twitter like by doing:

- placing google option closer to login form
- making google option bigger ( *though I feel it won't be good UI move* )
- giving a note to opt for google ( *quite strongly feel it definitely won't make sense* )

The reason I am not removing Twitter option completely are:

- want to give user an alternate option
- after a slightly *rough* survey I found: there will be quite a few users from twitter as well

Comment: Is Google sign in more important than your email sign in or are they of equal importance?

Comment: @BenjaminS I will weight them equally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion I would leave it as is and let the users choose (I would think more would use google than twitter anyway), but if you want to do it that way I see a couple ways you could do it:

1. Just tell the user your preferred option
   [image]
2. Have google as the default option showing, then under a dropdown panel of sorts have alternative options (twitter, fb, etc.)
   [image]
3. I don't know if it is applicable to your site but give some sort of value prop to using google, such as "Sign in with your Google+ account and receive 50 free points" or "Sign in with Google+ and connect with your friends easier"

P.S note that I moved Google to the top of both options, I believe that will help just by grabbing users that go for the first option.

Comment: Though 2nd option requires extra user click but that's more appealing to drive user (silently) to opt for Google. Thanks